# Get connected clients IP in Firebird

Tags: database, firebird

I have a Firebird database hosted on a server. Firebird can display a list of connected users, with username, role etc, with the `MON$ATTACHMENTS` table. But, I can't find out how to get IP address of one specific client.

Exemple : if the user "USER", from `192.168.1.77`, is connected on `192.168.1.2` (server), how can I get this `192.168.1.77` address with Firebird query ?

Edit : `MON$REMOTE_ADDRESS` shows the DHCP server address, not the local client one.

Comment: what is your connection string ? what is FB version ? what is your program and which client library it uses ? I just checked connecting IBExper from Win7 with fbClient 3.0 to a 2.1 server residing on Win2003  - and MON$REMOTE_ADDRESS correctly shows client address. I think incorrect client library might report wrong address to server... // BTW, you say almost the same - `of one specific client.` - so that client is different from others and reports wrong IP....

Comment: 1) do you have SuperServer or Classic Server ?  2) can you modify that client code to register correct IP into some table for your later use ?

Comment: I don't have the client program source (and can't access it), so I know absolutely nothing (same for server). Gonna ask my boss about a solution and will post it later.

Comment: For server you would have to check FB FAQs manuals what is the difference, then to determine which option - SS/CS/SC - was used during installation. With Classic Server mode each connection spans a separate fb_inet_server.exe and then you can check its network connection to client with OS means (firewall, netstat, etc). Other modes make different clients share same FB process, so that external observation is not possible.

Comment: by client above I meant not merely the program, but all - the computer, the program, its settings, the used "client library" specific to executive environment of the program... Mark below is developer of FB Java client library JayBird, and he says bugs in client lib should not affect the server's mon$remote though. So I think the connection string on that client should be different from the one on other clients. It should be connecting not directly to the db, but to some intermediate proxy (and then that proxy is what is seen and reported by the server as the remote client)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebird has an internal attachements table, where every current connection is stored. The remote address(es) for a user named `USER` can be queried like this:

```
select MON$REMOTE_ADDRESS
  from MON$ATTACHMENTS
  where MON$USER = 'USER'
```

Comment: The MON$REMOTE_ADDRESS displayed by Firebird isn't the client address, seems to be the server's one.

Comment: @Saphirel AFAIK it should be the address of the client (and in Firebird 3.0 address + port of the client)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but what does fill that field? is this server itself or a client library? When you use wire protocol, do you pass some data that gets conveyed into that field ?  or maybe his connection string is a proxy-chaining one....

Comment: @Arioch'The The server gets it from the socket.

Comment: Maybe there is software between the client and server, like fb scanner. If fb scanner resided on same machine as server, firebird would show the servers iP address and not the clients.

Comment: I have tested with both Firebird 3.0.0 and 2.5.6, and in both cases it reports the IP address of the client, so I guess the theories of Arioch'The and Ed Mendez could apply to your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested for the current client's connection, you could use the following query:

```sql
   SELECT MON$USER, MON$REMOTE_ADDRESS,
       MON$REMOTE_PID,
       MON$TIMESTAMP
     FROM MON$ATTACHMENTS
     WHERE MON$ATTACHMENT_ID <> CURRENT_CONNECTION
```

https://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rnfb210-admin.html